# Javascript looping through Page elements to change states?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

This is relatively simple, but I'm missing something.  I have 10 checkboxes on a page, in a table in a form.  They all have names and id's of add0, add1, add2, etc.  I wanted to build a "check/uncheck all" checkbox, but my code doesn't seem to be working.  On firefox, using firebug, but it can't seem to follow the script execution.

```
function checkboxprocess(current)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (current.checked)
        {
            document.getElementById("add" + i).checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("add" + i]).checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Checkbox:

```
echo "Select All: <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"add\" id=\"add\" value=1 onChange=\"checkboxprocess(this)\"><br>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra `]` in your code:

`document.getElementById("add" + i`**`]`**`).checked = false;`

And you don't have to check if is `current` checked each time in the loop, you can do it easily like this:

```js
function checkboxprocess(current) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            document.getElementById("add" + i).checked = current.checked;
            // current.checked will return true/false
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    Select All: <input type="checkbox" onChange="checkboxprocess(this)">
    <br /> <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="add0">
    <input type="checkbox" id="add1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="add2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="add3">
    <input type="checkbox" id="add4">
    <input type="checkbox" id="add5">
    <input type="checkbox" id="add6">
    <input type="checkbox" id="add7">
    <input type="checkbox" id="add8">
    <input type="checkbox" id="add9">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Forest for the trees, I guess.  Much simpler breakdown for my loop.